# multiple dynamically created jquery slider galleries on one page

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to create a page where the user can add jquery slider galleries to a page on the click of a button.

I have nearly got it working but am having problems with the rotation of the images on the additional sliders when there are more than one. and the original slder jumps about and only shows two images.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/25/

the additional sliders only loop round once and then stop

any help greatly appreciated.

code for fiddle

css:

```
    #slideshow {
        position:relative;
        height:350px;
    }
    #slideshow IMG {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:8;
        opacity:0.0;
    }
    #slideshow IMG.active {
        z-index:10;
        opacity:1.0;
    }
    #slideshow IMG.last-active {
        z-index:9;
    }
```

jscript

```
    var i;
    var topplus=50;
    function buildslider(i, id, content) {

        id = id + i;

        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
        newdiv.style.top = +topplus + "px";
        newdiv.style.left = +topplus + "px";
        newdiv.style.display = 'inline-block';

        newdiv.style.width = '320px';
        newdiv.style.height = '270px';
        newdiv.innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newdiv);            
        topplus=topplus+150;

        function slideSwitch() {
            var $active = $('#' + id + ' #slide_image.active');

            if ($active.length === 0) $active = $('#' + id + ' #slide_image:last');

            var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#' + id + ' #slide_image:first');

            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({
                opacity: 0.0
            })
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 1000, function () {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            setInterval(slideSwitch, 3000);
        });
       i++;
    }



    function addSlider() {    
        buildslider('i', 'draggable', '<div id="slideshow"><img id="slide_image" src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/mini-golf-ball.jpg" class="active" /><img id="slide_image"  src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/jon-raasch.jpg" /><img id="slide_image" src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/ear-cleaning.jpg" /></div>');
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type='button' value='add slider' id='addSlider' onclick='addSlider();'>
```

Comment: You should style everything based on a class, not giving them IDs. Multiple IDs is invalid

Comment: @Zeaklous sorry I dont quite understand what you mean, The id is the id of the surrounding div not the image, the image is not given multiple id's. can you give me an example?

Comment: @Zeaklous I have tried to change to a class but now the slider does not work http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/30/

Comment: I have also tried to do it this way but after the first cycle only the original slider carries on http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/33/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/34/ I'll post an answer

Comment: @Zeaklous thanks for the code, but to help myself and others who stumble across this page in the future, what was the main bit of code that needed changing to make this work? Thanks again and can you post as an answer to I can mark as answered

Comment: I know, I'll explain it all, just let me work out a couple kinks first

Comment: @Zeaklous yeah I noticed thats theres a delay before the slider apprears and the image cycle isnt 100% right, it jumps at one point

Comment: @Zeaklous the first image has the class set twice, the class 'active' as well as 'slide_image'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first: When dealing with adding dynamically created elements of unknown quantities, do your best to just use classes, not IDs, because they are more malleable and using the same ID on multiple elements is invalid HTML, *don't do it*.

After switching all the ids over to classes, I noticed that the new slideshows were absolutely positioned which should also be avoided with dynamically creating elements of unknown number. As a result, I instead floated the containers and used `clear:both` to make sure they didn't overlap.

Initially I just removed a large chunk of your `buildslider` function, but eventually I just opted to remove it completely because you can do what the function did in one line. I also removed a container div that did nothing but gave dimensions, opting to put that into the CSS instead.

As for the changes to the jQuery itself, it was relatively simple once the elements were given the appropriate classes. The biggest changes were that I moved the setInterval outside of the `slideSwitch` function to prevent it from overlapping each other, added a parameter (the parent object) to allow multiple slideshows to be run from different starting/transition points, and opted for mostly CSS based `transition: opacity 1s;` with jQuery's `.css` over jQuery's `.animate` for performance and ease-of-editability reasons. Instead of going to each `.animate` and changing the animation duration, you can just change the `1s` of the transition and it will apply it to all of the animations

As you saw in the rough demo I posted in the comments, there were was a glitch in one transition and the first slide was slow to load. The first issue was due to some overlapping issue in the transition from the last slide to the first slide and was solved by changing the `.animates` to `.css` and adding the CSS transition as mentioned earlier. The second problem was due to there not being an `active` class by default, so I simply added the class to first img in the appended HTML. However, this made it immediately appear so I added a `.animate` just after it is appended so that I don't have to worry about the iteration of the setInterval

Here is the full code

```
/* HTML */
<input type='button' value='Add Slider' onclick='addSlider()'>
<div id="content"></div>

/* CSS */
#content {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slideshow {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    width:270px;
    height:350px;
}
.slideshow img {
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:270px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.slideshow img.active {
    z-index:10;
}
.sdeshow img.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

/* Javascript/jQuery */
var i = 0;    
function slideSwitch($container) {
    var $active = $container.find('.slide_image.active');    

    if ($active.length === 0) { $active = $container.find('.slide_image:last'); }
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $container.find('.slide_image:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active').removeClass('active').css({
        opacity: 0
    });

    $next.addClass('active')
        .css({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, function () {
        $active.removeClass('last-active');
    });
}

function addSlider() {
    $('#content').append('<div class="slideshow"><img class="slide_image active" src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/mini-golf-ball.jpg" class="active" /><img class="slide_image"  src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/jon-raasch.jpg" /><img class="slide_image" src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/ear-cleaning.jpg" /></div>');
    var $addedElem = $('.slideshow:eq(' + i + ')');
    $addedElem.find('.active').animate({ opacity: 1 });
    setInterval(function() { slideSwitch($addedElem) }, 3000);
    i++;
}
```

[**Full demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/36/)

Please let me know if you have any questions related to my code

Comment: Thanks for the work you have put in. I understand why you have changed a lot of the code for CSS but there are reasons it was written that way. In my full code the height width top and left of the element are passed rto the buildslider function and that is why they are not set in css. I will try to deconstruct your code to work for me. As you have answered the problems with the post then I will mark this as solved